# Is there a way to artifically press a button on an xbox controller?

Tags: windows, xbox

I'm creating an application for a phone that will be able to be used as a controller on a computer. I want the phone to imitate how an xbox 360 controller would work. However, I'm not sure how to go about this. Is there any way I can trick the pc into thinking it's an xbox controller?

Answer (score 1):

View the source code for `DS4Windows` (Maps a Sony PS4 Controller to an XBox-360 Controller): https://github.com/Jays2Kings/DS4Windows/blob/jay/DS4Windows/DS4Control/X360Device.cs

Basically you need to pair to the device via Bluetooth and read the input. Map the commands to the Xbox ones and broadcast it or write to whatever application needs it.